# Backbone/marionette: adding an element before adding the collection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to use twitter bootstrap, backbone and marionette for a form. I want a label and a select next to it. I was able to display the select but now am having trouble adding a label before the select element.

```
var app = new Marionette.Application(); 
app.addRegions({

    region1: "#region1"

});
//.. model and collection here
app.typeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "option",
    template: "#item",
    initialize: function(options){

        this.$el.attr('value', options.model.get('id'));

    }
});
/* COLLECTION VIEWS */
 app.listview = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
              tagName: "select",
              id: 'type-select',
              itemView: app.typeView,
});


app.on("initialize:after", function() {
        //somelist is defined here
    var lv = new app.listview({
        collection: somelist
    });
    app.region1.show(lv);
});
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="region1" class="container">

</div>
<script type="text/template" id="item">
        <%= name %>
</script>
```

I want it to look like:

```
<div id="region1" class="container">
           <label for="type-select">Name</label>
           <select id="type-select"><option>...</option></select>         
</div>
```

But it always looks like:

```
<div id="region1" class="container">

               <select id="type-select"><option>...</option></select>         
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a composite view:

```
<script type="text/template" id="select-field">
    <label for="type-select">Name</label>
    <select id="type-select"></select>
</script>

app.listview = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
          template: "#select-field",
          itemView: app.typeView,
          itemViewContainer: "select"
});
```